# How to change the folder in the OPENROWSET functions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to insert some data into a table in SQL Server 2012. 
However, it can't open the folder for some reason. The book I am reading says I should change the folder in the OPENROWSET functions, but I am not sure how to do that. 
Can anyone help? Thank you very much!

Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Documents
(title, doctype, docexcerpt, doccontent)
SELECT N'Columnstore Indices and Batch Processing',
N'docx',
N'You should ．．．．',
bulkcolumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\TK70461\ColumnstoreIndicesAndBatchProcessing.docx',       SINGLE_BLOB) AS doc;
```

And the system gives an error when I run the code:

```
Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\TK70461\ColumnstoreIndicesAndBatchProcessing.docx" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
```

Answer (score 0):

The path and file 'C:\TK70461\ColumnstoreIndicesAndBatchProcessing.docx' must exist on the file system where the Sql Server database instance is running. So if this is a remote Sql Server instance you are connecting to with this script then you need to copy that file to a path on the server's file system and then use that path in the OPENROWSET function.